# What is the purpose of this case label?

Tags: c++, language-construct

Inside *boost/asio/coroutine.hpp* there is case statement inside the definition of the macro `yield` which seems to be inaccessible:

```
  switch (_coro_value ? 0 : 1) \
    for (;;) \
      case -1: if (_coro_value) \
        goto terminate_coroutine; \
      else for (;;) \
        case 1: if (_coro_value) \
          goto bail_out_of_coroutine; \
        else case 0:
```

What is the purpose of `case -1` since the switched value can only be either `0` or `1`?

Comment: Probably "no point/purpose".. my guess would be "the remnants of a "rock star" programmer who didn't know what the f he was doing".. either that or it's too clever for its own good.

Comment: @JesperJuhl This is exactly what I doubt...

Comment: why would you "doubt" it? To "doubt" something means to disbelieve it or not think it is correct..

Comment: `_coro_value ? 0 : 1` can be simplified to just `!_coro_value`

Comment: @JesperJuhl I had answered before you edit your comment! Your first comment satisfies me now.

Comment: You'll first have to make sense of the for(;;) sprinkled amongst the case statements.  This is Duff's Device at work.  You'll risk permanent brain damage, some odds the author did as well.  I hope he's okay.

Comment: Note that this is a *macro emulation of stackless coroutines*. It's "too clever for its own good" by definition.